# Accessing Kivy Screenmanagaer inside a screen's __init__ method

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to build an application that loads data from a JSON file and adds it to an MDList object. I would like the loaded items to take the user to a specific page when clicked. My implementation of the `__init__` finction is shown bellow:

```
def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        json_data_object = JsonData("data.json")
        # adds list item from JSON file to MDlist object 
        for i in json_data_object.data["lists"]:
            loaded_object = ListItemWithoutCheckbox(text="[b]" + i["list_name"] + "[/b]")
            self.ids["Container"].add_widget(loaded_object)
            
            self.manager.add_widget(ToDoListPage(name=str(loaded_object.text)))
            loaded_object.bind(on_release= lambda x : self.change_screen(loaded_object.text))
```

The first half of the for loop works as intended, adding the loaded objects to the `MDList` object. However the second half returns an `AttributeError`:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_widget'`

I have a theory that this is due to the `__init__` function running before the screen is added to the `ScreenManager()` object in the `MainApp()` class, shown below, but have no concrete proof of this nor any ideas for how to get around the issues.

```
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        # Setting theme to my favorite theme
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        Builder.load_file("styling.kv")
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(ToDoListView(name="ListView"))
        return sm
```

I will keep trying to work on the issue but I am struggling to come up with new ideas, so any help is greatly appreciated.

If I manage to crack this I will post my solution to this issue!

Thanks for any help :)

EDIT:

I have added a method to attempt to add the on_release functionality after the `__init__` method has run. On printing `self.parent` I still receive a `None` value. I have also attempted to use the `Clock` module of kivy as suggested in the comments by [John Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7254633/john-anderson) but I am still receiving the same `AttributeError` shown earlier in this question. My edited code now looks like this:

Class initialisation:

```
def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        json_data_object = JsonData("data.json")
        self.loaded_items = []
        # adds list item from JSON file to MDlist object 
        for i in json_data_object.data["lists"]:
            loaded_object = ListItemWithoutCheckbox(text="[b]" + i["list_name"] + "[/b]")
            self.ids["Container"].add_widget(loaded_object)
            
            self.loaded_items.append(loaded_object)

    def load_tasks(self, loaded_objects):
        for i in loaded_objects:
            # To test if i can access the screen manager
            print(self.parent)
            self.manager.add_widget(ToDoListPage(name=str(i.text)))
            object.bind(on_release= lambda x : self.change_screen(i.text))
```

Main app class:

```
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        # Setting theme to my favorite theme
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        Builder.load_file("styling.kv")
        list_view_screen = ToDoListView(name = "ListView")
        list_view_screen.load_tasks(list_view_screen.loaded_items)
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(list_view_screen)
        return sm
```

Thank you so much for even checking out this question!

any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: The `ids` in a widget are typically not assigned until after the `__init__()` method is run., so you cannot access then in that method. A fix is to delay the code that accesses the `ids` by using `Clock.schedule_once()` or some other technique.

Comment: Thank you John Anderson, this really helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

happy to say i finally found a solution to the issue. By abstracting the functionality of the `__init__` method into another method and making a partial call in kivy's `Clock` object, the function could utilise the screen manager object.

```
def __init__(self, sm,**kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.load_tasks, sm)) 

    def load_tasks(self, sm, *largs):
        json_data_object = JsonData("data.json")
        self.loaded_items = []

        for i in json_data_object.data["lists"]: 
            self.add_loaded_item_to_list(i)    

        for i in self.loaded_items:
            self.bind_on_release_to_loaded_item(sm, i) 

    def bind_on_release_to_loaded_item(self, sm, loaded_item):
        self.manager.add_widget(ToDoListPage(name = loaded_item.text))
        loaded_item.bind(on_release= lambda x: self.change_screen(loaded_item.text))
    
    def add_loaded_item_to_list(self, loaded_item):
            loaded_object = ListItemWithoutCheckbox(text="[b]" + loaded_item["list_name"] + "[/b]")
            self.ids["Container"].add_widget(loaded_object)
            self.loaded_items.append(loaded_object)
```

The `MainApp` class reverted to its original:

```
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        # Setting theme to my favorite theme
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        Builder.load_file("styling.kv")
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(ToDoListView(sm,name = "ListView"))
        return sm
```

Thanks again to [John Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7254633/john-anderson) for helping me get to this solution :)